# Is the Borg's existence common knowledge outside of Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, borg

The Borg,  unlike the other civilized enemies and allies of the Federation, has single-handedly laid destruction to entire worlds. Nearly everyone we see speaks of the Borg in hush tones and fear. But we mostly see Starfleet brass and higher up UFP politicians taking about the Borg. Has there been any civilian talk of the Borg? Is this living personification of a virus known to the general public? As a fact or even as a general boogie man?

Comment: The Hansens, who AFAIK weren't part of Starfleet probably knew more about them than any Starfleet people did

Comment: Another factor is that both the Enterprise-D and USS Saratoga had civilians on-board during their encounters with the Borg, so some civilians must have known something about them.  Add to the fact the El-Aurian refugees from the borg attack on their planet and we can see some people known about them.

Comment: Well, they got  federation council funding, and were just two people. I'm hoping for something more numerous

Comment: They did get Federation funding, but my understanding is they knew something about it before that funding too.  I haven't found much from Memory Alpha in my limited research, but it seems some people did know, I'm just not sure how widespread the knowledge was.  Interesting question

Comment: @cde to get funding you need to have something to be funded first. I wonder what the funding was, in a cashless economy. A ship, probably?

Comment: @peter yea, a ship and supplies for long term exploration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem the answer is **yes**

I have several sources to support this view.  First of all, there are the ships with civilians who were directly involved with the Borg.  Now, they wouldn't probably know about it to the same extent as Starfleet, but it would be pretty difficult to not see the Borg when you're jettisoned in an escape pod.  The *Enterprise-D* had civillians on board at the time [so that's quite a few people](http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_many_people_are_aboard_the_enterprise-d) who had the chance to see the Borg.  DS9 *Emissary* also establishes civillians were aboard at least the Saratoga as well:

> SISKO: Let's get the civilians to the escape pods, Lieutenant.

The Hansens, exobiologists, also were aware of the Borg, as evidenced by this [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Magnus_Hansen) quote:

> In 2353, Magnus and Erin Hansen petitioned the Federation Council on Exobiology to support them on an independent research mission to study the Borg

i.e they knew of the Borg and they weren't Starfleet members (that we know of).

The strongest piece of evidence I've found is this quote from DS9 *Homefront* which suggests that knowledge of the Borg is reasonably well known - Joseph (Sisko's father) runs a restaurant from what I can gather, so he'd see an awful lot of people.

> JOSEPH: I don't blame him. **I haven't seen people so nervous since the Borg scare**. Me, personally, I'd like to meet him. Though I have to admit, I'm a little suspicious about anyone who doesn't eat.

Importantly, though, although it seems that people were *aware* of the Borg, the amount they knew was fairly limited:

> Prior to the USS Enterprise-D's first encounter with the Borg, the Federation had knowledge of their existence, based on encounters with surviving members of species that had been destroyed by them (such as the El-Aurians). However, empirical data on the Borg was very scarce: for example, there were descriptions of cube-shaped vessels, but no information on what Borg individuals looked like, other than rumors that they were cybernetically enhanced.

So, if the Federation officials had reasonably little idea of the Borg, you could expect the Federation civillians would know even less.

(Source: [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Magnus_Hansen))

Comment: The quote from Joseph is the most compelling.

Comment: I can't really recall the **VOY** episode because I've seen it years ago (maybe a whole decade), but if I'm not mistaken, the 7/9 learns from the Hansen's ship log that they went after a **rumour** about a cybernetically enhanced species travelling by cube shaped ships. Now, I'm not saying that no civilian knew about the Borg, but _investigating a rumour_ and researching a fact seems to be two different things to me.